# Save custom Date and Time in created_at field Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I want to save a custom date and time in created_at field. Currently my model has

```
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I want to give my own date and time which I will receive from user current time.

How can I do this?

Comment: remove `auto_now_add=True` and migrate -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import:

`from datetime import datetime, timezone`

In `models.py:`

```
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False,blank=True, null=True)
```

this will allow your `created_at` field exist with `Null` value (being empty)

In `views.py:`

```
def time_function(request):
    #get your object
    object = Object.objects.get(xx=zz)

    #this will create date and time object with your current timezone
    date_time_now = datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)

    #assign time to your objects field
    object.created_at = date_time_now
    object.save()
```

Comment: this works fine, but when I check in my db the time is different there. Why is this happening.

Comment: @SALMANTAHIR time in database stores in its own way, you don't need to think about how it is stored. Django thought about it for you, if you want it to look differently you need to format it, in your backend or frontend, not in database

Comment: yes that's good but what if I want to see from Django admin . There date time is wrong. BTW Thank you for your answers

Comment: @SALMANTAHIR what do you mean by saing `date time is wrong`?

Comment: by wrong i mean Lets suppose I gave it 22:00:00 . On code level when I save it and retrieve it gives correct time 22:00:00 but when I check from django admin it gives 17:00:00

Comment: @SALMANTAHIR problem seems with your timezone, you are +5 hours from UTC, 17:00 is UTC time, it is not wrong, it is correct